# Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and virtualization in bios is enabled but getting error message

Tags: 22.04, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to install ubuntu 22.04 from the windows store but I get the following error:

```
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2-install
Press any key to continue...
```

however both the Virtual Machine Platform windows feature is enabled and so is virtualization in the BIOS. Can there be anything else causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this on another form online

Ran this command:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

rebooted and ubuntu launched. I didn't look into what the command actually does, so if someone would like to answer with additional details I'll accept the answer.

Comment: That's good info, and I'd encourage you to self-accept when the option becomes available (probably 48 hours?).  The `bcdedit` tool is what modifies the boot options for the Windows bootloader.  `hypervisorlaunchtype` is what tells Windows to actually *start* the Hypervisor (a.k.a. "VM manager"), which in this case is the "Virtual Machine Platform".  The default *should* have been `auto` already, but something had apparently changed that in the past.  Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 5):

I'd definitely recommend trying [@Dick's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1459070/1165986) first if you are having this problem, but another option when this occurs is:

- Go to *Turn Windows features on or off* in the Settings.
- See if the *Hyper-V* option is selected, and deselect it if so.
- Also deselect the *Virtual Machine Platform* at the same time.
- Reboot
- Re-enable the *Virtual Machine Platform* and reboot again.

Try WSL2.

If that works, and you need Hyper-V enabled on your system for other tasks, you *should* be able to:

- Deselect *Virtual Machine Manager*
- Re-select *Hyper-V*
- Reboot

WSL2 can make use of *either* VMP or Hyper-V.

If the above doesn't work, at the very least you'll have some more data points for additional trouble-shooting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running inside a Hyper-V VM, you need to run the following command on the host in a PowerShell command where `<VMName>` is your named VM.

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

All these didn't work for me. What worked for me was:

> Restart ⇨ Goto BIOS ⇨ Search for anything related to virtualization on your machine.
> ⇨ Mine was called: AMD... ⇨ enable it.

It worked.